# what is the best keymap for intellij, for an eclipse user

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I am typically an eclipse user on windows. I am now using Mac with Intellij, what should be my keymap so that I can be most productive as soon as possible. If I shift to eclipse keymap, would I be losing some of the shortcuts of intellij.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use IntelliJ own keymap since the 1st day. Even though it may slow down migration process a bit it will definitely be payed off in the future. Check e.g. this [Getting comfortable with IDEA’s Keymap, Navigation and Settings](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/getting-started-with-intellij-idea-as-an-eclipse-user/4/) chapter from the [guide for IntelliJ IDEA users coming from Eclipse](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/getting-started-with-intellij-idea-as-an-eclipse-user/).

For easier migration there is [Eclipse shortcuts mapping](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/eclipse.html#Shortcuts) cheat sheet.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, the link was helpful, working with intellij default keymap, and getting used to it quicker than I thought.